# Complicated Json processing - PHP

Tags: php, json

I am using this JSON: http://steamcommunity.com/id/mitch8910/inventory/json/730/2/

I am sorting through the "rgDescriptions" data with this:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/id/mitch8910/inventory/json/730/2/');
$json = json_decode($data);

foreach ($json->rgDescriptions as $mydata)
{
   //checking and adding data to a database
}
```

Each section in "rgDescriptions" contains a lot of information on a certain item. For each item I check some things, for example

```
if($mydata->tradable == 1){ //do somthing }
```

I now want to also use "rgInventory" from the JSON as well, and save the information in a database with the info from "rgDescriptions". Because I'm doing checks with the"rgDescriptions" data, not all items are saved into the database, so i can't just go through all the items in "rgInventory" and save them.

I want to do something like:

```
    foreach ($json->rgDescriptions as $mydata)
    {
        if($mydata->tradable == 1){ 
           foreach ($json->rgInventory as $mydata2){
              //I want to get the elements from rgInventory that are 
              // in the same place as the corresponding 
              //elements in rgDescriptions
              $id = $mydata2[$mydata]->id;
           }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: So my problem: while I'm going through $mydata, I also, for some of the elements in $mydata, want to get corresponding elements from $mydata2. So If I'm at the 5th element in $mydata and I want to use $mydata2, I want the 5th element from $mydata2 as well.

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @Viral I just edited the question, giving more specifics of what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rows = array();
$data = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/id/mitch8910/inventory/json/730/2/');
$data = json_decode($data);
$rgInventory = $data->rgInventory;
$rgDescriptions = $data->rgDescriptions;
foreach ($rgDescriptions as $rgDescData) {
    if ($rgDescData->tradable == 1) {
        $classId = $rgDescData->classid;
        foreach ($rgInventory as $rgInvData) {
            if ($rgInvData->classid === $classId) {
                $rows[] = array(
                    'classIdFromRgDescriptions' => $classId,
                    'dataFromRgInventory' => $rgInvData
                );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
var_dump($rows);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should do this the other way round and start the process by looking through all the rgInventory occurances.

Once you have a rgInventory object, the

```
rgInventory->classid . '_' . $rgInventory->instanceid
```

is in fact the key to the occurance of rgDescriptions that matches this inventory item.

So

```
foreach ( $json->rgInventory as $key => $inventory ) {

    $descKey = $inventory->classid . '_' . $inventory->instanceid

    if ( $json->rgDescriptions[$descKey]->tradable == 1 ) {

        // do whatever you want

    }
}
```

Comment: This would work. It is similar to what I actually used, which was Cetver's answer. Though it was like yours, it was kind of opposite, and I found it worked better with the rest of my code.

Comment: What! you used that complicated code rather than a simple straight forward piece like this. Your choice

Comment: Well, no. I didn't just copy his code over. I used the example of going through rgDescriptions first, and when I needed to, looking in rgInventory and comparing the classIDs. Like I said, it was similar to yours but the other way around.

Comment: Yea, but Inventory is the master record and Description is a subordinate. The names alone give that away. Plus searhing all the Inventory array for each description has to be a whole lot slower than a direct key based access

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're asking for (I believe RiggsFolly's answer to be correct), but:
Instead of rearranging the data within your php script you could store it more or less as-is in your relational database.

```
create table rgInventory (
  id int,
  instanceid int,
  classid int,
  ...
)
create table rgDescriptions (
  instanceid int,
  classid int,
  ...
)
```

Just iterate over $json->rgInventory and add each item as-is to the corresponding table and then do the same for $json->rgDescriptions.
Later you can query the data with a JOIN query on the instanceid (and probably the classid, too).

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  rgInventory as inv
LEFT JOIN
  rgDescriptions as desc
ON
  inv.classid=rgDescriptions.classid
  AND inv.instanceid=rgDescriptions.instanceid
```